# How to concatenate variables php/html?

Tags: php, concatenation

SO here is my code:

```
<?php
$image = ''; 
if (getUserChar($_SESSION['user_login']) == 1) {
    $image = 'warrior';
    echo '<div class="'.$image.'" stlye="top:'.$top_pos.'px;left:'.$left_pos.'px;"></div>';
}
elseif (getUserChar($_SESSION['user_login']) == 2) {
    $image = 'mage';
    echo '<div class="'.$image.'" stlye="top:'.$top_pos.'px;left:'.$left_pos.'px;"></div>';
}
elseif (getUserChar($_SESSION['user_login']) == 3) {
    $image = 'archer';
    echo '<div class="'.$image.'" stlye="top:'.$top_pos.'px;left:'.$left_pos.'px;"></div>';
}
?>
```

With that, the class seems to work fine. but with regard to the variables top_pos -- it doesnt.

Comment: you spelled it "stlye" try changing to "style"

Comment: "SO here is my code", I see what you did there;)

Comment: `$top_pos` and `$left_pos` don't change value inside the if. Could this not be simplified into a line or two? Try: https://pastebin.com/cnkKPBGV

Comment: syntax is correct..check u r getting `$top_pos` value from the source..first `echo` it..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your $top_pos and $left_pos variables are not being set or being overwritten somewhere.

```
<?php

function getUserChar($input) {
    return $input;
}

// I suspect you have not set these anywhere or are being over written somewhere
$top_pos                = 123;
$left_pos               = 321;
$image                  = ''; 
$_SESSION['user_login'] = 1;

$input = getUserChar($_SESSION['user_login']);

if ($input == 1) {
    $image = 'warrior';
} elseif ($input == 2) {
    $image = 'mage';
} elseif ($input == 3) {
    $image = 'archer';
}

echo '<div class="'.$image.'" style="top:'.$top_pos.'px;left:'.$left_pos.'px;"></div>';
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/184e6935fa39e733c145441c6a24be6651f41c25